# stored procedure parameters in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters

i have a situation like need to accept 50 input parameters to a stored procedure?
is this correct way to accept 50 parameters?
and how many parameters a stored procedure can accepts in mysql?
if any one knows better solution please give your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So far I haven't been able to find a limit noted in the MySQL documentation, but according to [this forum thread](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1589635) then at least 1000 parameters are possible.

If you can provide some more detail about what you're actually trying to achieve, then someone might be able to suggest a better approach.